# Error connecting to db in Wordpress wp-config.php get_env issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I have faced a really weird problem (at least to me) while modifying the wp-config.php file of the wordpress, specifically setting DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_PASSWORD etc through loading values from system level environment variables.

**Currently, in wp-config.php - this works**:

```
define('DB_NAME',          'wordpress');
define('DB_USER',          'wordpress');
define('DB_PASSWORD',      'wordpress_psw');
define('DB_HOST',          'wp-db');
```

**However this does not**:

```
/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', getenv('WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PASSWORD') );

error_log("DB_PASSWORD: ".getenv('WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'));

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', getenv('WORDPRESS_DATABASE_HOST') );

error_log("DB_HOST: ".getenv('WORDPRESS_DATABASE_HOST'));

define( 'DB_NAME', getenv('WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME') );

error_log("DB_NAME: ".getenv('WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME'));
```

I do not know why defining thes configs by getenv does not work.

I have this docker-compose.yml

```
  wp-db:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mysql:8.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress/db/data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sql
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress_psw
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  wordpress:
    build:
      context: ./wordpress
    ports:
      - '8002:8080'
      - '8443:8443'
    depends_on:
      - wp-db
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress/wp_src_code:/bitnami/wordpress
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DATABASE_HOST: 'wp-db'
      WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME: 'wordpress'
      WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PASSWORD: 'wordpress_psw'
      WORDPRESS_DATABASE_USER: 'wordpress'
```

**UPDATE**
Whenever I try to log the value obtained from getenv value it is being logged 4 times as defined in the docker-compose.yaml, however when it's actually being used and run the getenv value I think, returning empty string, or false.

```
error_log("DB_HOST: ".getenv('WORDPRESS_DATABASE_HOST'));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was a php config (clear_env) that has to be set in www.conf file in order to preserve the env variables while accessing from wp-config.php file. And adding into my Dockerfile file was sufficient:

```
RUN echo 'clear_env = no' >> /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```